# Why WeakReference still return the Object's Value?

Tags: android, weak-references

I wanna know how to use `WeakReference` in developing android application.So as i searched a lot in the internet i typed this code :

```
   {
        String kk = "Test";
        WeakReference<String> kkRef = new WeakReference<String>(kk);
        System.out.println(kk);
        System.out.println(kkRef.get());
        kk = null;
        System.gc();
        System.out.println(kk);
        System.out.println(kkRef.get());
   }
```

which suppose to eligible the `kk` object to `GC`, But in the console output it seems that `kkRef.get()` still return the `"Test"` value which supposed to return `null` as i read about `weakReference`

So Why it didn't return `null`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, `System.gc()` does not necessarily perform a full garbage collection run, and there is no guarantee that it will do so synchronously. Hence, it is not guaranteed to detect all weakly-held objects.

Second, the string is still held onto strongly, as it is a string literal in your code. That cannot be garbage collected ever, and so a `WeakReference` to it would still return the literal.

Comment: But i typed `kk = null` which remove the strong reference

Comment: @MohamedFadelBuffon: You removed *that* strong reference. The string literal still exists in your code. In Java, assignment (`String kk = "Test"`) does not make a copy of the object. The string literal cannot be garbage collected. Try using an instance of an object that you create yourself using the `new` keyword.

Comment: Thank u very much it works for me :) . But could u please expalin to me what you meant by `literal` .. Thanks in advance

Comment: @MohamedFadelBuffon: A literal in Java is any primitive value (`5`, `3.14159f`, `true`) or `String` (`"Test"`) that you enter directly into your Java code.